# Does lightbox ads hurt website traffic

Tags: advertising, traffic

The ad company that I use, publishes ads on my website is now offering a new ad type that is a big ad in a lightbox with a big close button and ad also closes if the user clicks outside the ad (lightbox).

The ad company says that it won't hurt website traffic at all and I can produce up to 12 times more revenue. well in the past 5 days that I have activated this type of ad the revenue has increased about 4 times but I worry if it has a negative effect on my website traffic specially as it show up every time that page refreshes.

Comment: These ads tend to annoy the user- so in that respect, probably. I know that whenever there is a pop-up of this type, I hit the back button fast and do not visit the site again. Check your bounce rate in Google Analyticis to make sure that it is not rising and check for a drop-off from search in general over time. BTW- I do this for sign-ups too. I came for content. If I do not see the content, I leave. I am pro ad however. I want people to make money. But it should not be a barrier to the content. It is like a cover charge to a club when you do not know if it is a dump, dive, or a joint.

Comment: @closetnoc actually the reason I asked is that I saw no changes in my google analytics so I thought either it doesn't have much effect or the effects will be visible after sometime. so I thought its not wise to wait and watch for a long time

Comment: I know that a lot of sites do this and so there has to be a reason. I just assume that most users are like me and duck out. One exception is when I already know the site and trust the content would be something I am looking for. But this is rare. It still annoys me. Rule #1: Do not p1$$-0ff the user. You have to decide. It may be that people are more patient that I am. Who knows for sure.

Comment: what if I just add a cookie when a user comes to the site in show the lightbox if the users goes to a second page?

Comment: That might be quite a bit more acceptable. Still annoying though. To me anyway. Worth a try! It certainly is a clever alternative!!

Comment: BTW- I do not mean to be discouraging. I want you to make money and be successful. Trust me on that!!

Comment: "...it show up every time that page refreshes." ... on every page?? I can just about handle a popup advert once per "site visit", but anything more than that is too annoying IMO. A "cookie" type thing is mandatory I would think.